# 10+ years in the job and placed under PIP

Tags: performance, ireland

I am over 10+ years in the job providing customer service in supply chain logistics. It is a sort of a cross functional role that requires a certain knowledge about freight forwarding / supply chain / planning. It is also unique role as I am trilingual - part of my jobs specs.

Recently, about a month ago I was told my performance is not reaching certain standards. Now I am on PIP. I read this "exit door ... over there". Person conducting so called meetings does not want to speak in English and switch to French for convenience. (note, I live in Ireland). In my view this is an attempt to remove me from my post.

Can you please advise me what are my options or is there anything that should be done to beat the "system" especially now. I would like to keep this job. (loads of experience and expertise doing it for 10+ years) Help please.

Comment: With respect to you being trilingual and the wanting to conduct the conversation in French, is French a language that you are fluent enough in to use in a business context?

Comment: I am not native French speaker but certainly well spoken and able to talk / write on any subject. Point is, my manager has not mastered English to the desired level. My impression is than any argument that I provide is only understood by two of us.  I am presented with bogus statistics that are way out from my own KPI that I maintain for myself. As it is becoming formal now I am simply panicking and to be honest quite surprised that after all these years it came to this. Now 'am literally told I am not good enough. (after 10+ years)

Comment: Duplicate of [I received a written warning for my performance, how can I save my job?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/22041) or [Are there any specific strategies for surviving a PIP?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/73958). See also: [Does receiving a Performance Improvement Plan suggest my job is on the line?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/19201)

Comment: Is it part of the job requirements to be able to speak French well? If so, having meetings in French doesn't seem (particularly) unreasonable, regardless of which language you prefer or where you are.

Comment: I am good at it. It is partially down to the routine but generally speaking experience and knowledge put together. It seems I am also the last one being there so long. There are no unions involved. I intent to beat the system but as you said odds are against me, I am well aware of that.

Comment: If you are not currently working for Keelings, you might consider applying there (please don't tell us whether you are or not). I will delete this comment in a few hours. with your qualifications, finding a new job should not be difficult.

Comment: If there are other people in the meetings, repeat every response in French also in English, for the benefit of "...."

Comment: Sometimes, politics make perfectly productive employees unwanted. I know places where "too old" employees are pushed towards the exit just because the boss wants fresh meat. 100% unfair. Rather frequent in France. As your PIP seems to make no sense, the reason behind them is certainly not rational. Either someone hates you personally, or your age, or whatever.